# Can I have a C type and a D type visa end-to-end?

Tags: resident-permit, schengen, legal

I have received a D type visa to study in Czech Republic. It starts on September 11th. But I would like to go there earlier. When applying to a C type (toursitic) Schengen visa, the issuing country obviously wants me to come back to my country after the expiry date.

What happens if I have a C type visa from another Schengen country from August 20th to September 12th? Should I as well come back and go again, or can I just activate my D type by the alien police and stay there after expiration of my C type visa?

A slightly related problem that I am facing is, is it possible to have a C type visa starts before a D type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have to return to your home country but for the last question on "is it possible to have a C type visa before a D type" I would say it is possible.

I'm in a similar situation - where my school term starts on end feb (& I don't want to go there too early) however I would like to visit Europe in January so I sent an enquiry to the embassy for the country which I would be staying in the longest - and they said it's possible.

Comment: What embassy? Has their immigration advice proven reliable in the past?